# Calendar throughout CakePHP site, but CakeBook says to not use a Model in a Component

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3, models

I have a small calendar widget-type thing on many pages throughout my site.  The goal is for it to retrieve events from X category that fall between Y and Z dates.

My assumption (I'm new to CakePHP) was that I should create a component, and have it do the query.  Something like this:

```
class CalendarComponent extends Object {

    var $uses = array('Event');

    function getEvents($category = null, $date = null, $limit = null) {
        $events = $this->Event->find('list', //conditions to get correct events
        return $events;
    }

}
```

BUT, according to [this CakeBook page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/998/MVC-Class-Access-Within-Components):

> To access/use a model in a component
>   is not generally recommended

So - where would I store this logic / model call if not in a component?  I've admittedly not used a component yet (or not created one anyway) due to lack of really understanding how I should use them - any snippet of advice on this is also VERY welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think writing a component is overkill in this case and it would be cleaner to put the `getEvents` method into the `Event` model.

Comment: I happen to agree with you.  i just wanted to show @Dave how to work with models in components.  I hate seeing people who slavishly follow guidelines like the development police are gonna come arrest 'em if they make a mistake and learn some things :D

Answer (score 3):

Great question in my opinion and I imagine one that comes up quite often.  I was actually dealing with a similar problem where I wanted some site-wide data gathering or functionality shoved into a component.

The first thing to keep in mind:

**The book is a guideline.**

These 'rules' aren't rules.  If there's a **good** reason for breaking the rule and you **understand** why the rule is being broken then break the damn thing!  Cake itself breaks this rule quite often.

Core components that require/use models:

- Acl
- Auth
- Sessions (fairly positive you can save session data to a model)

So, clearly there are use cases where you need to use a model inside a component.  How do you do it though?

Well, there's a couple different ways.  What I wound up going with?  Something like this:

```
<?php

    ModelLoadingComponent extends Object {

        public function startup($controller) {
            $controller->loadModel('Model');

            $this->Model = $controller->Model;
        }

    }

?>
```

That's it!  Your component is now setup to use `$this->Model`...just like you would in a controller.

**Edit:**

Sorry, to clarify:  no, you don't have to setup a new component to load models.  I was showing an example for how you could load a component in **any** model.  The `startup` function I used is a component-specific callback, there's a whole slew of them http://book.cakephp.org/view/998/MVC-Class-Access-Within-Components.  These callback methods make components **a lot** easier to work with.  I highly recommend looking at this part of the components tutorial if nothing else.

If you were working inside an `AppController` object you could call `$this->loadModel()` but we aren't working an `AppController`!  We're working with a component, really an `Object`.  There is no `Object::loadModel()` so we have to come up with a different way to get that model.  This is where `$controller` comes into play in our `startup` callback.

When the `startup` method is invoked by Cake it will pass the `$controller` object it's working with on this dispatch as the first parameter.  With this we're able to access controller methods...like `loadModel()`.

Why do we do it this way?

Well, we could use `ClassRegistry::init('Model')` in each of our component methods that need to use the model.  If you have 10 methods in your component and only 1 of them uses the model this might work.  However, what if you have 10 methods in your component and all 10 of them use the model?  Well, you'd be calling ClassRegistry::init('Model') 10 times!  That's a lot of overhead when what you really want is just 1 model object.  With this method the component is creating one model object.  The one we create in `startup`.

I hope this clarifies your questions and provides some insight into why I use this method for models in components.

Edit: Added a code clarification after I did some experimenting.

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time to answser!  You've lost me - so I have to make another Component specifically for loading models?  And - I thought you could load a model just by doing $this->loadModel('ModelName');  Lastly - what is the reason they say it's not recommended to load models in components?  Just - unorganized?  Or does it run slower or something?  Thanks again, and thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: I'm just gonna edit my answer to clarify some of these things.